# packrat does not show unused but all packages

Tags: rstudio, packrat

When I use in my RStudio project the packrat Menue "Clean Unused Packages…" all packages I have ever installed are listed, e.g. even those which have the line `library(<pkgName>)` in it.

The same happens when I call the function directly with

`packrat::unused_packages()`  or
`packrat::clean(dry.run = TRUE)`

What am I doing wrong?